# vstest.console.exe open nunit GUI but doesn't run tests

Tags: selenium, visual-studio-2013

I have a visual studio project which includes a test with selenium code. I am trying to run this using `vstest.console.exe` using command

```
vstest.console.exe C:\Code\SampleReportsProject\SampleReportsProject\bin\Debug\SampleReportsProject.dll
```

On running this command, it opens NUnit GUI window but doesn't execute the test.

On running again, I get message

> Starting test execution, please wait... Warning: No test is available
>   in C:\Code\SampleReportsProject\SampleReportsProje
>   ct\bin\Debug\SampleReportsProject.dll. Make sure that installed test
>   discoverers  & executors, platform & framework version settings are
>   appropriate and try again.